# confusion with Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle being in the Update method

Tags: unity, vector

I've got some code that looks like this:

```
    public void SomeClass: Monobehaviour{
    
    private smoothAngle = 0.0f;

    void Update(){

        var localDesiredVelocity = transform.InverseTransformVector(navAgent.desiredVelocity);
        var angle = Mathf.Atan2(localDesiredVelocity.x, localDesiredVelocity.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        smoothAngle = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(smoothAngle, angle, 80.0f * Time.deltaTime);
}
    }
```

From what I could gather from the documentation it's sort of a lerping or slerping of the angle value.

My confusion is , why is it in the `update` function. since, `desiredVelocity` is dynamic, it would make the angle dynamic. So, suppose in 2 executions of the `Update` function:

```
1st execution: 
  
var smoothAngle = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(0, 80, /other_parameters/);  
  
  
2nd execution:  
  
var smoothAngle = Mathf.MoveTowards(/someValue/, 82, /other_parameters/);
```

My point is , while `smoothAngle` is s/lerping due to the first execution in the update function, once new values are passed for it during the second execution, would it cancel the first `s/lerping` and follow the latest one, or how would it handle new values for it  in consecutive execution of the `Update` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're operating under a common misconception about functions like `Mathf.MoveTowards`, `MoveTowardsAngle`, `Lerp`, etc., which is the belief that these are "tweening functions", equivalent to saying:

"Over the next several frames, continue animating this property from value A to value B"

If that were the case, then calling them each frame would indeed be concerning, because last frame's invocation is "still running" and would need to be interrupted/halted to avoid conflict or weird stacking with the new invocation.

But that's not what these functions do.

These are just math functions, like `+`. They take some numbers, calculate some new numbers, and return them. That's all. They have no persistence, they have no memory of the frame before, and they do not continue executing on future frames.

So this line:

```
smoothAngle = Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(smoothAngle, angle, 80.0f * Time.deltaTime);
```

...will calculate an angle from `smoothAngle` that's one step closer to `angle`, with the size of that step being limited using the current frame time so that it does not exceed a speed of 80 degrees per second. It then returns that angle, and assigns that number to `smoothAngle`. Nothing else happens.

To make this object keep moving next frame, we have to call this function again, to calculate a new angle to advance `smoothAngle` towards.

Comment: thanks for the brilliant answer as always. But, one more confusion, show does `80.0f * Time.deltaTime` mean `not exceed a speed of 80 degrees per second`?  Time.delta is the time taken by latest frame to execute, how does multiplying it with a number give us a value to not exceed that number?

Comment: This last argument is the maximum size of the step we're allowed to take. If we want to move at a speed of 80 degrees per second, and frame lasts 1/60th of a second, then in a single frame we can move up to `80.0f * 1f/60f = 1.3333...` degrees. That's what's being calculated here: maximum speed multiplied by time interval equals maximum distance crossed in that time interval.

Comment: thanks a lot, really clear explanation. :-)